# Uploading large images are failing

Tags: 14.04, apache2, upload

When I try to upload an image file larger than ~100k through Wordpress and another upload script, I am getting a generic "http error".

I can upload smaller images without any problems.

I am using ISPConfig3 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I followed these steps and the changes were made without issue but that did not resolve my issue:

1. Create a php file with  and open it with your browser.
2. Look for Loaded Configuration File (this shows the actual conf. file in use) and edit upload_max_filesize and set post_max_size to the same value (or make it 0 to disable limit) in that file in root mode.
3. Execute: sudo service apache2 restart

I did not think it would solve it since the default was 2m and the file is much smaller than that.

I have also tried the following:

Same error with IE, FF, and Chrome

```
- added this to .htaccess file:
<IfModule mod_security.c>
<Files async-upload.php>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</Files>
</IfModule>
```

- deactivating all plugins
- changed themes and it was still an issue
- another posted suggested this, but I do not have this file:
  Edit the following file:

  /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf

Add this line (just below all of the other lines that start with ‘Fcgid’):

```
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
```

- found a post suggesting this:
  You can also add this to your wp-config.php file: define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64MB');
- uploads directory was 777 anyhow so no need to change to to 755 as suggested in other posts
- added the following to my .htaccess file:

  php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
  php_value post_max_size 64M
  php_value max_execution_time 300
  php_value max_input_time 300

Are there any logs that will tell me why the uploads are failing or even better, does anyone know why it is failing?

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

I did find the /var/log/apache2/error.log and tested the upload again tailing the log file and nothing showed up in the log.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the following settings in php.ini

```
 upload_max_filesize = 

 post_max_size = 

 max_execution_time =
```

And set them as

```
 upload_max_filesize = 64M

 post_max_size = 64M

 max_execution_time = 300
```

Once the change is made

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Edit: You may want to revert all your changes, like in .htaccess and that php file. I never used that mem setting in wp-coinfig, but that probably okay to keep

Also I have never changed chmod on any WordPress directory before. I always just unzipped and did a

```
 sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/wordpress
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go. If your running an ubuntu server 15 setup following "the perfect ubutnu server15 with apache and ispconfig" than you'll probably have the same probleme I did

I couldn't get anything over 100k to upload :(

Although I got settings right /etc/php5/cgi/php.ini and my joomla site was saying max upload 2000M (yeah i did overkill) I still couldn't get anything to go over 100k

So, I followed th instuctions that I found in a post (as also found by the poster above) and edited the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fcgid.conf to make it look like this :

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  FcgidConnectTimeout 200
  FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824
....
```

Then, as root you do :

```
services apache2 restart
service php5-fpm restart
```

to get all those configs swallowed up and miracles occur...
Apparently, fdgi limits to 100k upload if not stated otherwise... and this seems to impact only on ubuntu 15, because I don't think I have this problem on my ubuntu server 14.10...

Hope this helps

Regards